# aws golang docker elastic beanstalk connect to rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

So I am trying to connect a golang container running on elastic beanstalk to a rds postgres database and am having a lot of trouble doing it. Amazon documents how to connect every other language to rds insances (ruby, php, .net etc) but apparently they have yet to add documentation for go. I've been experimenting with stuff along the lines of

> db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres:postgres@tcp(UNIQUEtoINSTANCE.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432)/ebdb")

to no avail. (and yes my test password is postgres). I have literally spent most of this afternoon working on this, googleing it, tweeking the local instance and reuploading. The security groups are correct. Any advice in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated or better yet actual go code for connecting the two (I know I am not the first person to use aws and an sql database).

Comment: Any luck?  Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: I ended up switching over to heroku. AWS is amazing but not necessarily the easiest to use. It still very much deserves its place on people's resumes. Heroku (which is an abstraction layer over aws) has been an absolute breeze. The amount of time we spent dealing with server related stuff for us was under a quarter of what we were spending with AWS. It costs more so we will definately transition at some point, but we will probably add a guy to deal specifically with AWS at that point.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Good to know!  Thanks for the great response.